# How to know FirebaseRecyclerAdapter query is zero or not, exist or not

Tags: firebase

How to know FirebaseRecyclerAdapter query is zero or not, exist or not

I find some instructions on

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database

it says:

> Data and error events
>
> When using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter you may
> want to perform some action every time data changes or when there is
> an error. To do this, override the onDataChanged() and onError()
> methods of the adapter:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(options) {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        // Called each time there is a new data snapshot. You may want to use this method
        // to hide a loading spinner or check for the "no documents" state and update your UI.
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DatabaseError e) {
        // Called when there is an error getting data. You may want to update
        // your UI to display an error message to the user.
        // ...
    }
};
```

When I tried to use as follow:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Place, PlaceViewHolder>(options)
        {

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                // Called each time there is a new data snapshot. You may want to use this method
                // to hide a loading spinner or check for the "no documents" state and update your UI.
                // ...
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"data exists");

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"No data exists");
                }
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
            {
```

Error message is:

> Method does not override method from its superclass

So how can I solve this problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from another page:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
@Override
            public void onDataChanged()
            {
                // Called each time there is a new data snapshot. You may want to use this method
                // to hide a loading spinner or check for the "no documents" state and update your UI.
                // ...
                if (getItemCount() == 0)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"No data exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"data exists");
                }
            }
```